# dadurch versus durch die

Tags: preposition

Slow German podcast #182 has the following sentence:

> Und das sind nur drei der acht Länder, durch die diese Bergkette führt.

Would this sentence have the same meaning and be just as correct?

> Und das sind nur drei der acht Länder, dadurch diese Bergkette führt.

Answer (score 2):

You have two misconceptions.

The first one is simple. The adverb *dadurch* means *for that reason*. If you wanted to pickup a direction in a later sentence as in this case, you had to write *da durch* instead. In speech, the difference is the former is stressed on *durch*, the latter on *da*.

> Und das sind nur drei der acht Länder. Da durch führt diese Bergkette.

---

The second is you assume the *hier-* and *da-* adverbs mean the same as a preposition lead relative clause. They don't.

The *hier-* and *da-* adverbs are for reintroducing *another fact* independent from relative clause logic.

> An diesem Beispiel, durch das man es erkennt, zeige ich das.
>
> An diesem Beispiel zeige ich das. Dadurch erkennt man es.

The meaning is slightly different. *Dadurch* refers to the whole previous sentence, while the relative clause only refers to *dieses Beispiel*.

You may combine both:

> Die Bergkette, durch die dadurch unsere Tour führt, sind die Alpen.

Here, the *dadurch* reintroduces a reason given in one of the previous sentences.

Comment: Duden lists 3 meaning for dadurch and the first one is "da hindurch, durch diese Stelle, Öffnung hindurch", which, as I understand what you are saying, does not agree with what you say. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dadurch . Aside from that I do not follow your explanation.

Comment: *»Da durch«* on position 1 like in *»Da durch führt diese Bergkette«* is bad style. It sounds much better if you put it behind the verb (and move the subject to position 1): *»Diese Bergkette führt da durch.«*

Comment: According to Duden, even in meaning 1 (*through there*) it is written as one word »dadurch«. It seems like Janka, Hubert and myself all disagree with the Duden and would write »da durch«. The effect is similar to »auseinandersetzen«, which has a not very literal meaning of *to deal with*, whereas »auseinander setzen« indeed means *to make two people sit apart from each other*.

Comment: @Raketenolli: I that foolish attempt to rectify the connected and unconnected writing of words, the Rechtschreibreform created a lot of uncommon standards.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Yes, but I did it deliberately to avoid another complication of the example.

Comment: @Michael: What exactly you do not follow?

Comment: ich würde weder "da durch", noch "wodurch" mit mehreren objekten verwenden. "... ein tiefes Tal; da durch führt ...". aber bei 3 ländern würde ich sagen "durch die" oder "durch diese...".

Comment: @Janka: I wish I could tell you, but that's how little I understand from your response.

Comment: The *hier-* and *da-* adverbs aren't meant to replace the introduction of a relative clause. They are re-introducing a topic from a previous sentence under the aspect of the built-in preposition.

Comment: English example: *There are too many cars. **For that reason** there're traffic jams.* – *Es gibt zu viele Autos. **Dadurch** kommen die Staus zustande.*

Answer (score 1):

Pronominaladverbien *da(r*) + Präposition können keine Relativsätze einleiten. Das war vielleicht nicht immer so; bei Luther heißt es beispielsweise:

> Wenn aber ein Stärkerer über ihn kommt und überwindet ihn, so nimmt er ihm seinen Harnisch, **darauf** er sich verließ, und teilt den Raub aus. ([Lukas 11,22](https://www.bibel-online.net/buch/luther_1912/lukas/11/#22))

Heute müßte es *auf den* heißen.